# How to schedule jar file as event on aws EC2

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, job-scheduling

I wrote talend etl job and packaged it into an executable Jar file.

i want schedule this jar file to run every week once.

I am using Amazon AWS. Can it achieve what I wanted? If yes, what are the steps I should proceed with? If not what are other alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Linux, I recommend you to use the traditional [cron service](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) served by unix system.

**step**

1. Edit `/etc/crontab`
2. Write schedule and shell script to kick Talend job

Please be careful timezone setting.

**alternatives**

[Wikipedia - List of job scheduler software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_job_scheduler_software)

Comment: @nikita On Windows, I recommend JobScheduler or Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend putting your jar in a docker container and putting it into an EC2 instance on AWS. Cron job will work, however, but what happens if you are not signed in when your task is scheduled to execute? If you put the jar in the cloud it will always execute.